# What happens when I call the Microsoft SQL Server View from a stored procedure which implements pagination?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that implements pagination to get 20 records per page. Internally this procedure calls a view.

My question is what happens when the call is made. Does the view query the table to get all records for every page, even though I only need 20 records?

Example :

- A table has 100 records
- The procedure calls the view with pagination of 20 records for page 1. Does the view return with the result of all 100 records?
- Similarly when a call is made for page 2, does the view grab all 100 records again?

If so, isn't it redundant and not wise to use it ?
Please guide me in the right direction.

Query inside procedure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM v_trans_history 
ORDER BY created_date DESC
    OFFSET 20 * (1 - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

View :

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets tck WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN transaction_activities ta WITH (INDEX (idx_trans_actv_ttid_tid), NOLOCK) ON ta.ticket_id = tck.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN transaction_statuses ts ON ta.transaction_status_id = ts.transaction_status_id
LEFT JOIN error_status es ON ta.error_status_id = es.error_status_id
LEFT JOIN games g ON tck.game_id = g.game_id
WHERE ta.transaction_type_id = '1'
```

Comment: Without the definition of the procedure we don't know how your paginating the data.

Comment: To a greater or lesser extent, you should treat tables and views as *interchangeable* (indeed, you should be able to substitute one for the other without affecting any other code). Would you have the same concerns if you were querying a table? If so, why or why not?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my thought process was views give better performance than tables.

Comment: But is my concern valid does view get all records every time ?

Comment: @Larnu please take a look now , is that better ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever with table i dont have the same concern, its with view I am unclear weather it will grab the full set every call ?

Comment: With `OFFSET` then it is likely that the more row would be read for each page. For the first page you would read the "first" 20, but for the 2nd, the first 40, and then first 20 would be removed. This is, of course, assuming there are indexes to help the database order the data appropriately to start with.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: So for the 5th page, it would get all 100 and remove the first 80 records? @Larnu

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). More generally use hints only when you understand exactly what they do and you have a demonstrated purpose for using them.

Comment: Correct, @sandeshbnataraj . It, in a sense, it's like an `OFFSET 80 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY` is effectively a `TOP (100)` and then the "reverse" `TOP (20)` of that subset. For small data sets the cost will be negligible, but for large sets much more noticeable.

Comment: thank you @Larnu. Is there a better approach you are aware of to negate this?

Comment: @SMor Noted! will look into that.

Comment: See the link from @jarlh , Sandesh .

Comment: That `WITH (NOLOCK)` isn't really helping you. I promise.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn why is that? I thought nolock just says don't lock when querying the table. Will it impact performance?

Comment: @sandeshbnataraj That's not an accurate understanding of `nolock`. Nolock queries still create the same additional locking they would otherwise. What it actually means is "Don't respect other locks". This _can_ help a query go faster, but if it does it's because it's ignoring a lock that probably exists for a reason. In other words, it opens you up to returning wrong or duplicate data. It's not a magic "go faster" button.